# Any impact of changing SQL Server log shipping restore job schedule

Tags: sql-server, database, log-shipping

On the SQL Server log shipping secondary database server, I have 2 jobs `LS_Copy` and `LS_Restore`.

**Current schedule**: both jobs run every 30 minutes (all day)

**New schedule:** I want to change the restore job to run every 30 minutes between 10:00 AM to 7:00 PM and 6:30 AM to 7:30 AM. It won't be running for the remainder of the day.

The copy job will still have the same schedule, i.e., every 30 minutes (all day)

**Question:** do you know if making this change can create issues I am unaware of?

Comment: I would question why you need to do that? I suspect you have an XY problem....

Comment: Yes, I do not want to run anything between 7:30 to 10:00 AM, as the restore job causes the other jobs to fail.
And after 7:00 PM the aws server resources are changed to minimum configuration, a reboot happens during this, and there are no users after 7:00 PM so updating the secondary database is not a requirement.

Comment: so if LS_copy job keeps collecting the files, and restore happens as per any new schedule, would this in anyway make the secondary database out of sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the schedule to new one, everything is working fine. The copy job piles up the files and whenever restore executes, it processes all the queued files in correct order.